# ExtJS 4.2 Grid Header doesn't show correctly in IE

Tags: javascript, extjs4.2

The purpose of the following code is to popup a window which contains a 2 column grid.
It works fine in Safari and Firefox but fails to show properly in IE 8 and IE 10 (which our customers insist on using).
In IE, the 3rd hidden column will not be hidden, but cover 1st column instead.

I use default CSS of ExtJS 4.2, does that matter?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/extjs-4.2.1.883/resources/css/ext-all.css">
```

And here is my JavaScript:

```
    Ext.define('Base.Lov_4_2', {
        extend: 'Ext.form.TriggerField',
        defaultAutoCreate : {tag: "input", type: "text", size: "16",style:"cursor:default;", autocomplete: "off"}
        ,triggerCls: 'x-form-search-trigger'
        ,lovTitle: ''
        ,view: {}
        ,window:null
        ,windowConfig: {}

        ,showLov: function() {
            this.renderWindow();
            this.window.show();
        }

        ,onRender: function(ct, position){

            Base.Lov_4_2.superclass.onRender.call(this, ct, position);

            this.renderWindow();
        }

        , onTriggerClick: function(e){
            this.showLov();
            return false;
        }

        , renderWindow: function(){

            this.windowConfig = Ext.apply(this.windowConfig, {
                 title: this.lovTitle
                ,width: this.lovWidth
                ,height: this.lovHeight
                ,modal: true
                ,closable: true
                ,closeAction:'hide'
                ,items: this.view
            },{shadow: false, frame: false, frameHeader: false});

            if(!this.window){
                this.window = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', this.windowConfig);
                this.window.on('beforeclose', function(){
                    this.window.hide();
                }, this);
            }
        }
    });

    Ext.define('LovField.LOV_COM_SCR0010_4_2', {
        extend: "Base.Lov_4_2",
        lovTitle:'',
        triggerCls: 'x-form-search-trigger'
        ,initComponent: function() {
            Ext.apply(this, {
                lovTitle:this.lovTitle
                ,view: Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {

                    store: new Ext.data.Store({
                        id:"storeLOV_COM_SCR0010",
                        proxy: {
                            type: 'ajax',
                            url: this.url,
                            method: 'POST',
                            reader: {
                                root:"List",
                                totalProperty:"Count"
                            },
                            actionMethods: {
                                create: 'POST', read: 'POST', update: 'POST', destroy: 'POST'
                            }
                        },
                        fields:[{name:"CODE",type:"string"}
                            ,{name:"DESCR",type:"string"}
                            ,{name:"PERSON_SN",type:"string"}
                        ]
                    }),
                    columns: {
                        items:[
                            {id:'CODE',text:'ID',width:80,dataIndex:'CODE'}
                            ,{id:'DESCR',text:'NAME',width:100,dataIndex:'DESCR'}
                            ,{id:'PERSON_SN',text:'PERSON_SN',width:80,dataIndex:'PERSON_SN',hidden:true}
                        ]
                    }
                })
               ,dataComponentName:"LOV_COM_SCR0010"
               ,lovWidth:300
               ,lovHeight:300
             });
            LovField.LOV_COM_SCR0010_4_2.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
        },
        onRender:function() {
            LovField.LOV_COM_SCR0010_4_2.superclass.onRender.apply(this, arguments);
        }

    });

    Ext.onReady(function(){
        var querypanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            id: querypanel,
            frame: true,
            border: true,
            bodyPadding: 5,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: '100%',
            anchor: '20%',
            fieldDefaults: {
                labelAlign: 'left'
            },
            items: [{
                layout:'column', baseCls:'', border:false, items:[{
                    width:250, layout: 'form', labelAlign:'left', border: false, margin:'0 10 0 10',
                    bodyStyle: {background: 'transparent'},
                    items: [
                        new LovField.LOV_COM_SCR0010_4_2({
                            xtype: "LOV_COM_SCR0010_4_2",
                            lovTitle:'QUERY',
                            fieldMapping: [{column:"DESCR",field:"query_name"}
                                ,{column:"PERSON_SN",field:"person_sn"}
                            ],
                            selectOnFocus:true,
                            name:"query_name",
                            id:"query_name",
                            fieldLabel:"NAME"
                        })
                        ,{
                            xtype: 'hidden',
                            name: 'person_sn',
                            id: 'person_sn'
                        }
                    ]
                }]
            }]
        }); 
    });
```